# Xamarin.Auth with CustomRenderer does not open on Android

Tags: xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, xamarin.auth

I successfully got Oauth2 to work with my localhost implementation using iOS and this Xamarin example: https://github.com/rasmuschristensen/SimpleOAuth

However, using Android, only a blank grey page is displayed. No error messages. I cannot figure out why the:

```
protected override void OnElementChanged (ElementChangedEventArgs<Xamarin.Forms.Page> e)
```

event does not get fired in the LoginpageRenderer.cs for Android.

This is the best and most recent Xamarin.Auth sample I found so far. Any ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is now fixed in the new Xamarin.Auth 1.3.